# Encode complex JSON structure using Perl

Tags: json, perl

I want to encode the result of a MySQL query into a JSON string using [`JSON::XS`](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON::XS). The JSON string needs to look like this

```
{
    "database" : "dbname"
    "retentionPolicy" : "mytest",
    "tags" : {
        "type" : "generate",
        "location" : "total",
        "source" : "ehz"
    },
    "points" : [{
            "precision" : "ms",
            "timestamp" : "ts1",
            "name" : "power",
            "values" : {
                "value" : "val1"
            }
        }, {
            "precision" : "ms",
            "timestamp" : "ts2",
            "name" : "power",
            "values" : {
                "value" : "val2"
            }
        }, {
            "precision" : "ms",
            "timestamp" : "ts3",
            "name" : "power",
            "values" : {
                "value" : "val3"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

The `points` array with each point's `values` element is giving me immense headaches.

Here is the code block that generates the JSON

```
my %json_body = (
                'database' => $db_name,
                'retentionPolicy' => $retention,
                'tags' => {
                    'source' => $metric_source,
                    'type' => $metric_type,
                    'location' => $metric_location
                }
                );

# loop through mysql result
while ( ($timestamp, $value) = $query->fetchrow_array() ) {
    my %json_point1 = (
                        'name' => $series_name,
                        'timestamp' => ($timestamp * 1),
                        'precision' => "ms"
                      );
    %json_point2 = ('value' => $value); 
    %json_values = (%json_point1, 'values' => \%json_point2); 
    push(@all_values, \%json_values);       
}
$query->finish();

# Encode json
my %json_data = (%json_body, "points" => \@all_values);
$influx_json = encode_json(\%json_data);
```

I think the line `push(@all_values, \%json_values)` is my problem. If I pass `%json_data` as a hash reference, only the last value from the `while` loop is retained. If I use `%json_values` directly, the encoded JSON is messed up because it loses the structure.

Any hint would be appreciated. And please bear with me: this array and hash references are already making my head explode.

Comment: What do you currently get with your encoded JSON?

Comment: Do you have `use strict` on in your Perl script?  I think the scope for `%json_point2` and `%json_values` could cause you problems.  Make sure you use `use strict`, and you probably want to declare `my %json_point2` and `my $json_values` inside your while loop.

Comment: @Sobrique and TobyLL I have never thought about this. You are both so right. Thanks a lot for pointing me into the right direction.

Comment: Please, you *must always* `use strict` and `use warnings` at the top of every Perl source file you write. It is offensive of you to ask for free help with your code when you haven't made even this minimal step to try to solve the problem yourself.

Comment: @Borodin the script actually uses both strict and warnings right from the beginning. I just copied here the part of the script that causes problems. Even thou I used strict I misplaced the scope of the variables. Nevertheless thanks for pointing to its importance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you problem will be because you're using a globally scoped hash for `%json_point` and `%json_point2`.
You see, the root of this is - you simply don't get a list of hashes. You get a list of hash *references*.

So the problem here is - when you push a reference to your hash into `@all_values` - you're pushing the same reference each time. But then you're overwriting the contents of the hash that you're referencing.

Try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my %hash_thing;
my @all_values; 

for ( 1..3 ) {
   %hash_thing = ( "test" => $_ );
   push ( @all_values, \%hash_thing ) ; 
}

print join ( "\n", @all_values );
print Dumper \@all_values;
```

And you'll see you have the same 'value' 3 times:

```
HASH(0x74478c)
HASH(0x74478c)
HASH(0x74478c)
```

And so if you dump it, then of course - you don't get the right array - and so your encoded JSON doesn't work either.

```
$VAR1 = [
          {
            'test' => 3
          },
          $VAR1->[0],
          $VAR1->[0]
        ];
```

The simplest fix is to use `my` to scope the hashes to the loop. (And turn on `use strict;` and `use warnings` if you haven't.)

Alternatively, you can use a hash reference like this:

```
my @all_values; 
my $hash_ref;

for ( 1..3 ) {
   $hash_ref =  { "test" => $_ };
   push ( @all_values, $hash_ref ) ; 
}

print @all_values;
print Dumper \@all_values;
```

Because `$hash_ref` is a scalar, and it's a reference to an anonymous hash, it can be inserted into the array by value, rather than by reference.